# How can I use Wordpress to authenticate a user in a spring web application?

Tags: java, wordpress, spring

Is there a way to authenticate a user using wordpress security, something similar to authenticating with facebook or twitter?  It seems that when using facebook to authenticate, an application gets something injected into its session to allow the requesting application to know that the user has been authenticated and is logged in. Is there something in wordpress or  something I can write to provide this facility.

I would like to have a wordpress site for static information and for the more dynamic type information use a spring web application.  Similar to what you would do with an apache web server hosting html files and move to tomcat for the jsp.

Comment: There is a plugin for wordpress to allow it to act as an OpenID provider, and a Spring Security extension to support OpenID logins, that would probably be the easiest approach to code.

Comment: I was able to use the database to auth a user but could not add it to my session for each request.  I have also created a PHP script to utilize the wordpress code to identify valid login but still could not put this info on my session.

Comment: How does facebook and the other social network app do this?  Stackoverflow uses this method so it is possible.

Comment: They use OpenID and/or OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do [OpenID authentication with Spring Security](http://www.packtpub.com/article/opening-up-to-openid-with-spring-security). If you don't want to do it yourself you may want to consider using [Janrain Engage](http://janrain.com/products/engage/) to support all kinds of "social logins".

Comment: There is also [Spring OAuth](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth), [Spring Social](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social), and [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).  All provide clientside support, the two Spring projects have some authentication features serverside as well (client apps in OAuth2 terms), and Scribe also has OpenID (I think).